# How to check the status code of an Async Http Session Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, async-await, aiohttp

```py
async def review(url, session, **kwargs):

try:
        #this checks the method from the list of ARGS kinda deleted the code 
    if method == 'GET':


        async with session.get(url) as response:

                # i did some printing in the code after the if condition but it was not executed 
            if await response.status_code == 200:
                print('[bold green]`[+]` [default]Target is responsive')
                print(response.data)
                return await response


except Exception as err:
    print(f'[red]ERROR {err} Target {url} is not stable ')
        url_obj['stable'] = False

else:
    url_obj['stable'] = True
    status = response.status_code
finally:
    if url_obj.get('stable') is True:
        return f'Target is stable'
    else:
        return f'Target is unstable status code {status}'


async def main(url, **kwargs):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        data= await review(URL, session, **kwargs)
            print(data)
           

def probe(url, **kwargs):
    asyncio. run(main(url,**kwargs))
```

I get this error when I import this code and run

`ERROR: 'ClientResponse' object has no attribute 'status_code'` Target http://localhost:8080/site.html is not stable
Traceback (most recent call last):

point to note i hosted the site locally and I get a response from the browser
i guess am missing something in the await response.status_code or rather not implementing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `status_code` to `status` -- looks like that's what it's called in the [ClientSession](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html) class.